# how do I graph $f(x)=1/(1+e^\frac{1}{x})$ except for replacing variable x with numbers?

Tags: calculus

How do I graph $f(x)=1/(1+e^\frac{1}{x})$ except for replacing variable $x$ with numbers?

Besides, [I get the picture of the answer online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZb7X.png) and do not understand why $x = 0$ exists on this graph.

Comment: Do you know the standard curve-sketching techniques?—find where the function is defined, find where the function is positive and negative and zero, find the derivative and thus where the function is increasing and decreasing, find asymptotes....

Answer (score 0):

Large and small positive $x$ have limiting behaviours that will help with s sketch, and you can show $f(x)+f(-x)=1$ to infer what happens when you rotate to negative $x$. As $x\to0^-$, $1/x\to-\infty$ so $e^{1/x}\to0$ while $f\to1$. Therefore, as $x\to0^+$, $f\to0$, giving the discontinuity in the diagram (that's what the white circles are for).

Comment: Thanks.But why there is still a line between interval (0, 1) on y- axis?

Comment: @Angel "How does the function $f$ behave as $x\to0$?" is a mathematical question. "why does Desmos (or other package) draw its graph in this particular manner?" is a Desmos question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the "exact" graph. However, there are methods in calculus from which you cn find the nature of the curve and hence "draw" the graph.

A few basic analysis techniques are as follows:-

1. $f' \left( x \right)$, physically gives the slope of tangent to the curve at a point $x$ so that the following things can be said about $f$ from the sign of $f'$.
   $$f' \left( x \right) > 0 \Rightarrow f \text{ is increasing}$$
   $$f' \left( x \right) < 0 \Rightarrow f \text{ is decreasing}$$
   $$f' \left( x \right) = 0 \Rightarrow f \text{ has a stationary point at } x$$
2. $f''$ gives the rate of change of $f'$, so that the convexity can be commented upon as follows
   $$f'' \left( x \right) \geq 0 \Rightarrow f \text{ is convex}$$
   $$f'' \left( x \right) \leq 0 \Rightarrow f \text{ is not convex (it is concave)}$$
3. If $f' \left( x \right) = 0$, then you can find whether $x$ is a maximum or a minimum 
   (or an infflection) using $f''$ above.

These basic properties gives the rough nature of the curve and you can then graph your function.